# Temporizador mediante Timer y un TextView

Tags: kotlin, timer

Estoy creando una aplicación basada en un Quiz, necesito meterle un temporizador y que el usuario vea el tiempo que le queda en en TextView y estoy intentando hacerlo con un simple Timer y TimerTask. Si remplazo el setText() por un Log.i me hace la cuenta regresiva, sin embargo en el TextView no refresca. Muchas gracias!

````
private lateinit var temporizador: TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        temporizador = findViewById(R.id.temporizador)

        val timer = Timer()
        var segundos = 6

        timer.schedule(object: TimerTask(){
            override fun run(){
                temporizador.setText(segundos) // esto no
                Log.i("Diego", "$segundos") //esto funciona
                if(segundos != 0){
                    segundos --
                } else{
                    timer.cancel()
                }
            }
        },1000, 1000)
    }
}```
````